# hasSystemFeature is not returning anything

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I'm having a strange problem. I'm implementing a bluetooth connection in an android app. In the manifest I have permissions for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Also I have these intents in the activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Since I am using a service and receiver for bluetooth process in the background I also have this permissions for the service:

```
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
```

Now, inside the service, I am calling to the following code:

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
   //it is true. bla bla bla
}else{
   //it is false. bla bla bla
}
```

Well, I cannot understand why, if I enter in debug mode, the getPackageManager is not returning anything. If I put a boolean variable with this line in the if, I can clearly see that nothing is returned. In fact, it is like if the code were killed in that moment because any other line in the code is accessed but I can still operate the app. Is it because what is being killed because of an error is the service and not the app itself? how can I debug this? Because I cannot see any error line. Any idea where the error is coming from?

EDIT: I'm running it on Android 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something additional: the function was called inside the constructor of an object that I was calling from the service. You need to pass the context to the object:

```
your_object = new your_object( getApplicationContext() );
```

and inside the object constructor:

```
public class your_object{

 public your_object(Context context){
     context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
}
}
```